# Docker container not running - Docker-compose

Tags: django, docker, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I am trying to run a django-react app in docker containers and trying to deploy it on digital ocean.

Here is my docker-compose script

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    image: "${WEB_IMAGE}"
    container_name: website
    command: gunicorn server.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file: .env

  nginx:
    image: "${NGINX_IMAGE}"
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web

  tensorflow-servings:
    image: "${TENSORFLOW_IMAGE}"
    container_name: tensorflow_serving
    ports:
      - 8501:8501
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Here you see nginx and web are listed, but not web. I get `502 Bad Gateway - nginx/1.21.3` error

[image]

**Update:**

When I insert the wrong IP in `DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1` in the `settings.py`, the docker container of the website appears but then I get `server error 500`. When I insert the correct IP address of the droplet I get `502 Bad Gateway - nginx/1.21.3` error`, and the container of the website does not appear on the droplet anymore.

Comment: what is ${WEB_IMAGE} ?

Comment: hey @TobiasS., `${WEB_IMAGE}` is defined in the `Github workflows` with the `docker-compose -f docker-compose.ci.yml build`. This runs locally fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the droplet I did

`docker ps -a` and there it appeared!

`33 minutes ago   Exited (3) 33 minutes ago`

So I followed it with

`docker logs <container name>`

And the error was in the `ALLOWED_HOSTS`